# How to use deploy ssh key to clone private repos using Chef 12 on AWS OpsWorks

Tags: github, ssh, chef-infra, ssh-keys, aws-opsworks

I could clone public repos using Chef 12 on AWS OpsWorks as follows:

```
execute "get code" do
user "root"
cwd node['conf-cookbook']['project_root']
command "git clone #{app['app_source']['url']}"
end
```

but I don't know how to use deploy ssh key to clone private repos - I have searched a while and see a potential solution as follows:

```
git node['conf-cookbook']['app_dir'] do
  repository "ext::ssh -i #{app['app_source']['ssh_key']} -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no #{app['app_source']['url']}"
  checkout_branch "master"
  action :sync
end
```

which did not work with the error msg:

```
---- Begin output of git ls-remote "ext::ssh -i -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----
MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEApaViIRinBrusrE....[key detail]7xAOmo3NAmqcPxdrOI+hZJHh5KRvrQPLHY
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no git@github.com:harrywang/app-main.git" "HEAD" ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: Warning: Identity file -----BEGIN not accessible: No such file or directory.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname rsa: Name or service not known 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-i` takes a path to a key file, not the actual key data itself. Use the `application_git` cookbook for setting up deploy keys with Chef.

Answer (score 5):

the following works according to @coderanger's suggestion:

```
application node['conf-cookbook']['app_dir'] do
  git app['app_source']['url'] do
    deploy_key app['app_source']['ssh_key']
  end
end
```

Comment: You could skip the `application` resource but having it is fine and the code wouldn't actually be any shorter with an explicit `application_git` usage :)

Comment: @coderange thanks a lot. I am learning application_python from you :)